# Update query "updatable query" issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access 2003, I'm trying to take a table and if any Indicator = 1 for ANY line of a given ID, make all lines = 1 for that ID

For Example, if we have:

```
ID   Indicator
Jack 0 
Jack 0
Jeff 1
Jeff 0
Mark 1
Mark 1
```

Would become:

```
ID   Indicator
Jack 0 
Jack 0
Jeff 1
Jeff 1
Mark 1
Mark 1
```

Since both Jeff and Mark have at least 1 line with Indicator = 1 I want to make ALL their lines = 1.

This is my attempt so far, but I keep getting an error "Operation must use an updateable query" (I think because the select statement is not a table... you can't update a query)

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Indicator)=1)))
List ON Table1.ID =List.ID SET Table1.Indicator = 1;
```

What is a good way to do this quickly and efficiently **without making a temporary table**? Or would a temporary table be the best/most efficient solution?  This will clutter up my database quite a bit since there are 8 lines I have to do this on... the table I'm opperating on is ~300 MB.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more detail on how you determine what `ID`s are to be updated and which are not.  SQL needs declarative logic in order to be able to make that determination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
UPDATE T1 SET Indicator = 1 
WHERE Indicator = 0
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 AS T2 WHERE T2.Indicator = 1 AND T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET indicator = 1
 WHERE id IN ('Jeff', 'Mark') --etc
```

If you wanted to only update the rows where the value isn't already 1:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET indicator = 1
 WHERE id IN ('Jeff', 'Mark')
   AND indicator != 1
```

Comment: If I put my select distinct statement in the WHERE like you have instead as a JOIN like I had, it works great, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Indicator] = 1, [Table].ID = [ID]
WHERE Exists (SELECT * FROM [Table] t WHERE ID = t.ID and [Table].Indicator = 1);
```